# How to set a separate learnable learning rate for each parameter in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am a little bit confused about the learnable learning rate for each parameter in Pytorch.

I want to set a separate learnable learning rate for each parameter. The learning rate and model parameters will be optimized together during the training process.

I find some code on stackoverFlow：

```py
    optimizer = optim.Adam([
            {'params': net.layer1.weight},
            {'params': net.layer1.bias, 'lr': 0.01},
            {'params': net.layer2.weight, 'lr': 0.001}
        ], lr=0.1, weight_decay=0.0001)
```

This method solves the problem of setting a fixed learning rate for each parameter, but it cannot allow the learning rate to be trained along with the model.

I tried to define a class with learnable learning rate:

```py
    class Learner(nn.Module):

        def __init__(self, net, in_channels, num_classes):
            super(Learner, self).__init__()
            self.learner = net(in_channels, num_classes)
            self.task_lr = OrderedDict()

        def forward(self, X):
            out = self.learner(X)
            return out

        def define_lr(self):
            for key, val in self.named_parameters():
                self.task_lr[key] = nn.Parameter(
                    1e-4 * torch.ones_like(val, requires_grad=True))
```

and then:

```py
    model_params = list(model.parameters()) + list(model.task_lr.values())
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model_params, lr=args.lr)
    adapted_state_dict = model.cloned_state_dict()

    #####compute loss#####
    #......
    ######################
    
    model.zero_grads()
    loss.backward()
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if param.grad is not None:
            adapted_state_dict[name] -= model.task_lr[name] * param.grad.data
    model.load_state_dict(adapted_state_dict)
    optimizer.step()
```

But this method still cannot train the learning rate.

Feel free to ask if more code is needed to explain the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by training learning rate? What would the target be? [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11243) is an example of "learning `lr`", it was done with reinforcement learning before so what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Also, you cannot use `OrderedDict()` as it won't register parameters. Use [`torch.nn.ModuleDict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleDict.html) instead (works almost like exactly like dictionary but parameters are registered).

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I want to implement the Meta-SGD algorithm, which is based on the MAML algorithm to assign an independent learning rate to each model parameter and the learning rate will be updated in the same way as the model parameters during the training process.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I tried `torch.nn.ModuleDict`, but there is an error appears in the function `define_task_lr_params` : `TypeError: torch.FloatTensor is not a Module subclass`

Comment: Use `torch.nn.Parameter(1e-4 * torch.ones_like(val))` when adding to Module Dict with specified key. You could also create your own optimizer with learnable parameters, but that is up to you.